# In IEEE conference latex file, my pictures and tables are merged/overlapped with text

Tags: diagrams

[image: Figures merged with text]

In IEEE conference latex file, my pictures are merged/overlapped with text. I have attached the screen shot of the file. Is it possible to make the picture merge two columns. Please help me with this. My last date to submit is the day after tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're probably stating the width in absolute terms, such as 8cm or something like that. Use a fraction of `\columnwidth`, such as `width=0.8\columnwidth`. Can you show a minimal example of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have different ways of setting the size of a figure.

You can use **\textwidth** command within the **width** parameter, like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

By using the **\textwidth** command, you determine that the figure will not have a width that is greater than the width of the text, i.e., the width of the column.

Or you can use the **scale** parameter:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5\textwidth]{myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

The scale resizes the figure relative to its original size, so it is not guaranteed that it will not overlap the text. In this case you have to try different scale values and adjust it to the space you have available for the image.

Comment: Thank you very much cebento, it was very helpful. I have a small problem with tables, can you help me please.
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176543/table-merging-with-two-columns-and-text-in-ieee-conference-latex-format

Comment: Hi @JerilK, if I was able to help you solving this problem, please mark it as an answer, so others can see that this question is answered.thank you.