# Table merging with two columns and text in IEEE conference latex format

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

[image][image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzZpi.png): ht*emphasized text*tp://i.stack.imgur.com/MP5IU.png

Dear Sir or madam,

The table i created in ieee latex template is being fixed to one column, its extending for the entire width. Please help. Thank you

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{4.5cm}p{2cm}}
    \toprule
    \centering\textbf{Technique Used} &
    \centering\textbf{Premise Considered} &
    \centering\textbf{Attributes} &
    \centering\textbf{Approach} \cr
    \midrule
    Potential Fields \cite{howard2002mobile} &
    Location information and range &
    Balanced deployment with the help of repulsive mechanism, when in proximity to obstacles &
\cr
\cline{1-3}
%
DSS Algorithm \cite{heo2003intelligent} &
Location information &
A profitable scheme to conserve energy during deployment of a WSN divided into clusters &
\multirow{-2}{2cm}{Virtual forces} \cr
\hline

Co-Fi \cite{ganeriwal2004self} &
Location information &
Ditributed scheme to conserve energy and provide regulated coverage fidelity &
\cr
\cline{1-3}
VEC, VOR, Minmax \cite{wang2006movement} &
Location information &
Identify coverage holes and enabling sensors to move away from dense area &
\multirow{-2}{2cm}{Computational geometry} \cr
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Location information and varying topology problem.}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **resizebox** environment to specify the width of your table. In this example I set the width to 12cm.

```
\resizebox{12cm}{!} {
  \begin{tabular}
   %the content of your table
  \end{tabular}
 }
```

Comment: Dear Madam, 
again thank you very much, it got solved, but the text size inside the table has been minimized. Is there any way to increase the text size. @cbento

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `\columnwidth` instead of `\textwidth` in

```
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}p{0.15\columnwidth}p{0.2\columnwidth}
                                  p{0.3\columnwidth}p{0.15\columnwidth}}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,booktabs,lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}p{0.15\columnwidth}p{0.2\columnwidth}p{0.3\columnwidth}p{0.15\columnwidth}}
    \toprule
    \centering\textbf{Technique Used} &
    \centering\textbf{Premise Considered} &
    \centering\textbf{Attributes} &
    \centering\textbf{Approach} \cr
    \midrule
    Potential Fields \cite{howard2002mobile} &
    Location information and range &
    Balanced deployment with the help of repulsive mechanism, when in proximity to obstacles &
\cr
\cline{1-3}
%
DSS Algorithm \cite{heo2003intelligent} &
Location information &
A profitable scheme to conserve energy during deployment of a WSN divided into clusters &
\multirow{-2}{0.15\columnwidth}{Virtual forces} \cr
\hline

Co-Fi \cite{ganeriwal2004self} &
Location information &
Ditributed scheme to conserve energy and provide regulated coverage fidelity &
\cr
\cline{1-3}
VEC, VOR, Minmax \cite{wang2006movement} &
Location information &
Identify coverage holes and enabling sensors to move away from dense area &
\multirow{-2}{0.15\columnwidth}{Computational geometry} \cr
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Location information and varying topology problem.}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]